# Jmeter GET request, https returns 503, http return 200

Tags: https, jmeter, haproxy, http-status-code-503

I'm preforming a simple test with Jmeter. A GET request, that works fine if I do it over http, but when I switch to https I get 503. There is an HAproxy between the client(Jmeter) and the server responsible to respond the request. Without going into much detail is there any Jmeter config, or HAproxy that pop's into your mind that I could be missing?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are targetting a server in HTTPS that uses SNI.

You are facing this issue:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57935

A workaround is to upgrade httpclient version of JMeter (don't forget httpmime, httpcore)

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. With curl, postman and browsers works fine. I will try the HAproxy logs

Comment: Is not that straight forward I already did that, and unless I have to set a flag somewhere it doesn't work

Comment: Even if you replace the jars I guess Jmeter still uses the deprecated http client from the new jar (httpclient-4.5)

Answer (score 0):

As per your last comment you are using SNI so facing a bug in JMeter:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57935

To workaround this you can upgrade to httpclient by doing the following:

1/ Remove from jmeter/lib:

- httpclient-4.2.6.jar
- httpmime-4.2.6.jar
- httpcore-4.2.5.jar

2/ Add to jmeter/lib:

- httpclient-4.5.jar
- httpmime-4.5.jar
- httpcore-4.4.1jar

Comment: With curl, postman and browsers works fine. I managed to reproduce the problem with SoapUI. I'm using the latest stable version of Jmeter. On a last instance it could be HAProxy config, but I did some other tests and found that using a simple java application to connect to the same URL I can reproduce the two different behaviours (503 and 200).

Comment: After http-client.4.3.jar looks like the main HTTP request class was deprecated and replaced by a new one. Using the deprecated to do the request I get 503 using the new one I get 200. So is it the HAProxy config or Jmeter (http client 4.2 version) and SoapUi(http client 4.1) just not following the pace? I also replaced Jmeter http client versions to the latest but I'm guessing it still calls the deprecated class from the new jar and still doesn't work.

Comment: In this case it would be JMeter, is your URL an HTTPS one ? with SNI ?

Comment: Yes, HTTPS. With SNI, yes.